# Run on server option not appearing in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm learning SpringMVC framework and checked out a copy of their code:
https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-basic/trunk/
I can do maven build, install and everything. But on Eclipse, run on server option never appeared. I have tomcat server up and running, also got plugin for eclipse. Why run on server option is missing? This is a Ubuntu machine.
When I tried the exact same thing on my Windows machine, everything was fine. It has the same version of eclipse and all sorts of plugins installed as the Ubuntu machine. I was able to launch it from Eclipse "run on server" option there.

Can someone help me to figure out why? Thanks.

Comment: Looking for proper solution in 2021 as recently started learning Spring MVC. Any help please?

Answer (score 125):

Did you create a Web Project?  If you right click on the project and go to Properties > Project Facets is Dynamic Web Module selected?

Comment: Checking "Static Web Module" will do the job, too.

Comment: Looking for proper solution in 2021 as recently started learning Spring MVC. Any help please?

Comment: this solution worked perfectly and my project is running now on the live server.
Please make sure that you have checked the Dynamic web Module.
Steps:
Right-click on project->goto properties->project facets->check the Dynamic Web Module.

Answer (score 35):

I had a similar issue. The Maven projects have different structure than "Dynamic Web Projects". Eclipse knows only how to deploy the Dynamic Web Projects (project structure used by Web Tools Platform).

In order to solve this and tell Eclipse how to deploy a "maven style" projects, **you have to install the M2E Eclipse WTP** plugin (I suppose you are already using the m2e plugin).

To install:
Preferences->Maven->Discovery->Open Catalog and choose the WTP plugin.

After reinstalling, you will be able to "run on server" those projects which are maven web projects.

Hope that helps,

Comment: I do not find any WTP plugin in the catalog.

Comment: On the searching box type WTP and click Enter. It should come in a while.

Comment: did not help :-( but then i combined it with the accepted answer, and it started working.

Comment: This fix also resolves the issue if someone is missing the Debug As Server. One fix, two missing menus. And thanks to @hoonzis.

Comment: Looking for proper solution in 2021 as recently started learning Spring MVC. Any help please?

Answer (score 28):

The topic is old but today I was facing the same problem, I imported a Maven project and when I tried adding to Tomcat it did not show the project. What worked for me:
**Properties** >> **Project Facets** and then check the options: 
**Dynamic Web Module** + **Java** then click in apply.
I hope it helps :)

Comment: Super!! @Rodrigo Almeida

Comment: Looking for proper solution in 2021 as recently started learning Spring MVC. Any help please?

Comment: I was trying to run maven restfull web application,Followed the above steps and it worked for me too. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 14):

For me worked:
Right click on project > Properties > Project Faces > change Configuration from "custom" to "Default configuration for Apache Tomcat v7.0" > OK and then Run on Server option has appeared.

Comment: Looking for proper solution in 2021 as recently started learning Spring MVC. Any help please?

Answer (score 11):

Follow the below steps:

1) Right click on your maven project.

2) Select Maven

3) Update Project

4) check the

- update project configuration from pom.xml
- refresh workspace resources from local filesystem.
- clean projects.

That's it.

Answer (score 4):

Do you see any servers in server view in eclipse? Probably simply you have not created any server instances.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you lost some configuration, check jar dependencies in properties -> Deployment Assembly. If you miss something, try to add dependencies again.

in my case, fixing this, Run on Server appear again.

Answer (score 1):

There is only 1 thing that fixed this for me. In the pom.xml, add the tag:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Then after saving that, when you right click on the project you should now see the "Run As... Run on Server" option showing up.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the following

1. remove `/WebContent` from `Deployment Assembly` and add `/src/main/webapp`
2. Add Library (Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries), `Server Runtimes`

This got me working, in addition to @alanbartczak answer.

Answer (score 0):

we have to install the M2E Eclipse WTP plugin 
To install: Preferences->Maven->Discovery->Open Catalog and choose the WTP plugin.

And restart eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue when i created a new workspace in STS. 
Project => right click => Maven option was also missing.
I tried this below steps and it worked.. hope it helps someone else. 
Project => right click => configure => convert to maven project and then the option to run on server appeared.

Answer (score -2):

Right click on the project, go to "Run as", select "Run configurations" and create a run configuration.