# Run on server option is not coming in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, apache, maven

I have created a spring mvc project [this link](http://www.programcreek.com/2014/02/spring-mvc-helloworld-using-maven-in-eclipse/) but after building this project I am not getting run on server option on my project.

I have seen [answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166882/run-on-server-option-not-appearing-in-eclipse) but it does not resolve my problem. see screenshot[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12895734/1700321.

Comment: @AleksandrM after doing this only I got these two options

Comment: Are you sure you're running the [enterprise edition](https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplersr2) of Eclipse as opposed to the [standard edition](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/lunasr1) targeted at plain-vanilla Java developers?

Comment: @PriiduNeemre Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)

Comment: Whereas it should be something like `Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)`. The easiest way to solve this would be to just go ahead and download the enterprise edition of Eclipse and not waste your time on downloading & installing individual plugins. (Probably safe to close this question now?)

Comment: @ankit if you are starting to work with Spring, a good option available is to use STS (Spring Tool Suite), check: https://spring.io/tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed my eclipse to [enterprise edition](https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplersr2) and it worked for me

credits Priidu Neemre