# Issues in setting up Authentication Flows project

Tags: eclipse, authentication-flows

I tried different ways to import "https://github.com/OhadR/Authentication-Flows" project into eclipse, but none of the import type is working.

It will be of great help if you can guide me with the same.

Thanks,
Harika

Comment: Are you trying to import .zip file?? If yes then unzip your project and then try to import your project.

Comment: @Anshul Tyagi : I did an unzip and tried to import. I was able to import using "import" -> "import" -> Maven -> Existing Maven Project in workspace. Though the projects got imported, I feel its not the right way because I am not able to build them successfully.

Comment: please see my answer below.... let me know if it helps... note that you import the pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

"Authentication-Flows" is a maven project. After you clone it, you will find pom.xml in the root directory (Authentication-Flows/client).

If you want to import it to Eclipse, click File -> Import... -> Maven -> Existing Maven Project.

HTH

Comment: I selected sub project and imported, thats the reason I was not able to build successfully. Now I am able to build but unable to deploy to tomcat. From readme file that is in the project - it says war files can be deployed to tomcat. So, I should be able directly deploy to tomact from eclipse too right? Am I missing something?

Comment: no, you are not missing a thing. you should be able to deploy the war to tomcat. what is the problem that you see?

Comment: On right clicking on authentication-flows project -> Run as -> Not able to see Run on Server option. Also, I tried to right click on the tomcat server directly and trying to add "Add and Remove" throws an error "There are no resources that can be added or removed from the server.

Comment: are you sure that this is related only to auth-flows? if you create another WAR and try to deploy it to tomcat - it works?

Comment: I did not create a war file. I am trying to deploy to tomcat directly from eclipse. Both are same right? Either way should work. Yes, my other projects are working.

Comment: read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166882/run-on-server-option-not-appearing-in-eclipse for me, combination of the first 2 answers helped.