# I can't see "run as server" option on my web project

Tags: java, tomcat9

I am using `tomcat 9.0` server and I can't run my maven Web project as server. I have installed Eclipse WTP for that but it dint work.

What am I missing?

[image: run as server missing]

Comment: Would you mind posting more details about the project here? Your pom-file maybe?

Comment: Hi, have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166882/run-on-server-option-not-appearing-in-eclipse)? Maybe some of the answers will work for you.